# Codeigniter API, Database Error Request Returns Object instead of set response

Tags: ajax, rest, api, codeigniter

I am experiencing an issue when i am using rest api on codeigniter, i have the following code on my api controller:

```
public function index_post()

{

    $input = $this->input->post();
    $data = array();

    try {
        $this->db->insert('attorneys', $input);
        $data = array('id' => $this->db->insert_id(), 
                      'message' => 'Attorney has been added'); 

        $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data = array('error_number' => $this->db->_error_number());
        $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

When i receive an error upon encountering a duplicate entry in the database since a filed was set to unique i receive an object as response from my ajax post request which is:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/"+location.pathname.split('/')[1]+"/api/attorneys",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data)
                {   
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#attorneyList").append('<div class="list-info">'+
                                                '<label><b>'+$('#inputAttorneyName').val()+'</b></label><br>'+
                                                '<label>Law Office: <span>'+$('#inputLawOffice').val()+'</span></label><br>'+
                                                '<label>Phone: <span>'+$('#inputAttorneyPhone').val()+'</span></label><br>'+
                                                '<label>Email: <span>'+$('#inputAttorneyEmail').val()+'</span></label><br>'+
                                              '</div>'); 
                    $('#attorneyIDs').val($('#attorneyIDs').val()+data.id+",");
                    $('#addAttorneyModal').modal('hide');
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

My console.log returns this object:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the **responseText** you will see that what was returned was an error page. The error is because you tried to insert a duplicate value in a field that, most likely, requires unique values. In this case, the "name" column already contains the value "Lawrence Boadilla".

You need to do something validation to check for those kinds of conditions before attempting an insert.

The `try` block won't help because CodeIgniter does not throw exceptions from the database classes.

Likewise, you cannot check the return from `$this->db->insert()` because the error means `insert()` does not return but instead will stop script execution. At least while you have error reporting turned on that's the case.

Comment: Are there no other choices?